# (Needle, Haystack) with 2 arrays, confused

Tags: php, arrays

Have been trying to figure out this simple problem for 3 days and don't understand why the function removes only some of the values, but leaves others in place.

This is function checks a list of bad domains against a list of good domains, if it finds a bad domain, it removes it from the good domains list.

Here's my code:

```
// check each bad domain, against each array in good array list

$bad_domains = array('youtube.com', 'facebook.com', 'google.com', 'twitter');

$good_domains = array(
'http://www.wufoo.com/',
'https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/105790754629987588694',
'http://studioduplateau.com/ss=',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=tic-toc',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=tic-toc',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=tic-toc',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=tic-toc',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM',
'http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM',
'lastofthemohicans.com'
    );

function remove_excluded_domains($good_domains, $bad_domains) {
    for($x=0; $x<count($bad_domains); $x++)
    {
        for($y=0; $y<count($good_domains); $y++) 
        {
            if(strpos($good_domains[$y], $bad_domains[$x]))
            {
            unset($good_domains[$y]); 
            $good_domains = array_values($good_domains);
            }
        }
    }
    return $good_domains;
}

$spider_array = remove_excluded_domains($good_domains, $bad_domains);
```

For some reason it returns:

```
[0] => http://www.wufoo.com/
[1] => http://studioduplateau.com/ss=
[2] => http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM
[3] => http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM
[4] => http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM
[5] => http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM
[6] => lastofthemohicans.com
```

So it removes all **http://twitter.com/?lang=tic-toc**, but leaves all **http://twitter.com/?lang=KA-BOOM**..

Why does it do that? I tried play with array_values, but it still doesn't work.

Sorry for the silly array values, just wanted it to stand out so it's more clear. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `foreach` loops, because that way you don't have to use `array_values()` function. So your `remove_excluded_domains()` funciton should be like this:

```
function remove_excluded_domains($good_domains, $bad_domains) {
    foreach($bad_domains as $bad_domain){
        foreach($good_domains as $key => $good_domain){
            if(strpos($good_domain, $bad_domain) !== false){
                unset($good_domains[$key]); 
            }
        }
    }
    return $good_domains;
}

$spider_array = remove_excluded_domains($good_domains, $bad_domains);
```

---

**Note:** If you want the array to be indexed numerically then use `array_values()` function on the returned array, like this:

```
$spider_array = array_values(remove_excluded_domains($good_domains, $bad_domains));
```

Comment: wow, thank you! I also realized as per Arman's comment that if I added a counter of domains outside of the loop, it would not decrease the count($good_domains). But your solution is even more elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code rearranges the array called `$good_domains` whenever a match is found, thus decreases the `count($good_domains)` each time, but does not reset the `$y` value.

Add this:

```
$y--;
```

Under this:

```
$good_domains = array_values($good_domains);
```

Comment: thank you, you're right, if I just counted the number of domains outside of the loop and do  for($y=0; $y<$counter_domains; $y++)  it also works. I went with Rajdeep's answer because it made the code even more elegant than what I wrote. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @Arman Ozak, I removed my answer, but please check the documentation before you say it's wrong! http://php.net/strpos. It returns an int or a false. Not a true.